# "Players failed to load content" when starting the Midnight mission

Tags: halo-4

I am unable to play the Midnight mission in Halo 4. The error message I get is `Player failed to load content. A player maybe missing downloadable content.`

I have inserted the second disk and downloaded whatever I needed from that disk. Nothing is working, I do not have XBox Live, do I need XBox Live to access this mission or is the game messed up?

Answer (score 1):

Midnight is one of the campaign missions, and it's included on the disc.  There's no DLC involved.  One of two things may be happening:

- The game is trying to load some content from the Disc 2 install which has become corrupted on your hard drive.  You can [remove this data](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/xbox-games/manage-games-data) and reinstall, which might fix the problem.  Since this data is primarily for War Games and Spartan Ops, I think this is somewhat unlikely, though.
- Your disc is bad.  It's possible it's defective or has been damaged.  In this case, your best bet is to contact the store you purchased it from or Microsoft directly and ask for a replacement.